# Gitlab CI/CD with Selenium in multi-container docker-environment

Tags: php, docker, selenium, continuous-integration, gitlab

We are developing a webapplication, which runs in three containers (MySQL database, Nginx webserver, PHP FPM).
Docker-Compose is used to manage the containers.

The current goal is to bring automated tests that makes use of Selenium into the pipeline of gitlab.

Within the gitlab-ci config I would launch the three containers using docker-compose and run our tests.
This however feels a bit complicated.

Is there a better, more clean way to set up testing?

Comment: Why does that feel complicated?

Comment: Because it's docker-in-docker. But if that's the common way people do it, I will stick to it

Comment: Have you considered running the tests in a separate container?